# ¿Qué codificación utiliza el prefijo \x (barra invertida x)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii, criptografía

Estoy tratando de adivinar la clave secreta para descifrar un mensaje usando Python 3. Sé que el mensaje va a ser algo como: `FCSC{`.

El punto débil de la operación XOR en criptografía es que A XOR B XOR A = B (no entiendo mucho esta parte). Así que cuando se conoce la parte del mensaje en texto plano M para el correspondiente mensaje cifrado C, se obtiene inmediatamente esa parte de la clave como K = M XOR C.

```
>>> cypher = bytes.fromhex('d91b7023e46b4602f93a1202a7601304a7681103fd611502fa684102ad6d1506ab6a1059fc6a1459a8691051af3b4706fb691b54ad681b53f93a4651a93a100
1ad3c4006a825')
>>> plaintext = b'FCSC{'
>>> key = ''.join(chr(c ^ m) for c, m in zip(cypher, plaintext))
>>> key
'\x9fX#`\x9f'
```

Parece ser ASCII, pero usualmente ascii se muestra en plain text con python ...

Comment: No es ASCII. El caracter `\x` es un prefijo que indica que el byte en cuestión no se puede mostrar como ASCII, por lo que te lo muestra directamente en binario (hexadicimal más bien) tras `\x`. Por tanto el primer byte de la clave es mostrado como `\x9f` y es un byte de valor binario 10011111. Eso no es ASCII, y tampoco utf8. Una clave criptográfica no tiene por qué ser texto válido, es una mera secuencia de bytes. Ocurre que el siguiente sí que casualmente corresponde a un carácter ASCII (la `X`) y así te lo muestra

Answer (score 0):

lo único que te puedo decir es que el \x es como Python expresa los hexadecimales si no quieres que se cuelen caracteres usa print(bytes(x)) creo que haci te lo mostrara en hexadecimal no se mucho de esto

Comment: podrias poner un ejemplo?, en caso no sepas podrias adjuntar la documentacion o una pagina donde aparezca un ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es mejor ver la *llave* de un algoritmo de encriptación (el que sea) como un arreglo de bytes y no como una cadena. De esta forma, te evitas todas las *complicaciones* o *confusión* que puede venir de las distintas codificaciones de las cadenas, ya que una misma cadena puede tener diferentes representaciones en memoria y, al final, es la secuencia de bytes la que realmente se utiliza como clave.

Por eso, puedes mejor *extraer* la parte de la clave así:

```
encriptado = bytes.fromhex('d91b7023e46b4602f93a1202a7601304a7681103fd611502fa684102ad6d1506ab6a1059fc6a1459a8691051af3b4706fb691b54ad681b53f93a4651a93a1001ad3c4006a825')

plaintext = b'FCSC{'

llave = bytearray()
for c, m in zip(encriptado, plaintext):
    llave.append(c ^ m)
print(llave.hex())
```

Al final, imprimirá la representación hexadecimal de la secuencia de bytes (el mismo formato que has usado para la entrada).

Sobre la expresión `a xor b xor a = b`, voy a escribirlo así:

- sea `encriptado = llave xor plano`
- la expresión `(encriptado xor llave) == plano` va a ser verdadera, ya que si sustituimos `encriptado` por su *fórmula*, nos va a quedar: `llave xor plano xor llave == plano`

En términos prácticos, si conocemos el texto plano y el texto encriptado, pero no tenemos la llave, podemos deducirla fácilmente haciendo la operación `xor` del encriptado con el texto plano.

Esta es la razón por la que el algorítmo `xor` se considera **tan débil** en criptografía.

Puedes comprobarlo tu misma, si con la llave que dedujiste en el punto anterior haces lo siguiente:

```
nuevoencriptado = bytearray()
for c, m in zip(plaintext, llave):
    nuevoencriptado.append(c ^ m)
print(nuevoencriptado.hex())
```

Esto va a imprimir el resultado de la encripción de los primeros bytes del texto plano, que debiera coincidir con los primeros bytes encriptados de la secuencia de donde construyes la variable `encriptado`.

También puedes derivar el *texto plano* utilizando la *llave* que ya *averigüaste* sobre el encriptado, por ejemplo:

```
nuevoplano = bytearray()
for c, m in zip(encriptado, llave):
    nuevoplano.append(c ^ m)
print(nuevoplano.decode())
```