# ¿Cómo descifrar un código de encriptación AES cuya clave puede ser estimada?

Tags: python, python-3.x, criptografía

Quiero decifrar un archivo en hexadecimal que fue encryptado porque no conozco el password. La clave de encripcion fue encryptado con scrypt, y el texto con AES:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import scrypt
from Crypto.Util.number import long_to_bytes

for password in range(0,9999):
    # generate the private key from the password and salt
    k = scrypt(long_to_bytes(password), b"FCSC", 32, N = 2 ** 10, r = 8, p = 1)
    # decode the dictionary entries from base64
    salt = b"FCSC"
    cipher_text = open("output.txt", "rb").read()
    # create the cipher config
    cipher = AES.new(k, AES.MODE_GCM)

    # decrypt the cipher text
    decrypted = cipher.decrypt(cipher_text)

    print(decrypted)
```

Lo único que sé es que el comienzo debe empezar por la FCSC. Sin embargo me devuelve:

```
(fcs_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Security\FCSC\lapin>python crack_lapin.py
b'K\x0b\xea\x8d\xbcku_Q\xa0\xdef\x84\xe9j\x95\x9cv+(\xb7\xad\xa2cf\xfel\xd5\xd9`x\xc9\x156A&G\xe1\xad|]8\x9b\x11\xe9\x96\xca]\x87\x8a\xc2q+*\xf1\x00\x85r\x96V\x11\xbd\t\x17Q\x04Q\x96\xf7\xb4\r\x0b\x9ff\xfay\xf3\xcf\x02\xf0d\x8b\xd0Nq\x85\xc1\xdbH\x1e\x0f\xb1\x83\x81y\xc6\x07\xdc\xbc\xa5J \x165~\xc42\x1c\xfa\xd8I9\x80\xe60\xc2/9\xa2<\xc2~!]\xfacT\xb5a\x99>\xa8\x88\xcf\xd2W\xad\x88\xc7\x97Zzg\xd1\x95\xd4\x08a]\xf0\xff\x8f\xd23Ps\xe8\xb7\xc6\xa0C!\xb4Lp1\x07\xb8y\x8c\x90\xc9\x12k\x1cs\xf3\xa5\x88+V+|&5\xfd\x14*,\t\xd50T\x94\xee\x14\xfa\xd0\x1cY\xfa\x81\xe0(\x8c\x19\xc3'
b',\x182\xa6\x12\x16)\x1b\xbfG\x947\x1f\xf7\xd6V\xd6\x92\xf8X\xe9\xec/\xfb{\x81\xf3\xf6\x9c,\xa2\xd2\xf5Q\xbb\xa4\xfb\xed\xa3\x00\'\xe0fYc\xab"\xecH\xd2]R\xf0Lb[pN\xadn\xb5\x00\x9e\x13l)f\tD\x81\xb6\x00l\xe2\xfbV\xcb\xf3\x17\x8e\x82\xf9\xbfb\xf7\xab\x9c\x7f\x98Z\x90\xf5\xe8\xc6^\x9f\x9e\xd4\xb9\x03\x18\xfe[\xab\x92prj\xe7s\x08\xbc\x1a\xfb\x02\x18\xba7u\xb1\x92\x96)\x80\x12\x16\xdc\xda\x17n\xd3l\xc6m\xbe6{\xd00\x04V\x1c\x87=T\x16\xa3E\xd2\xcb\x92f \x1a\xfae\x0e\x8bS\xf2\xf3\xff\x135M"0\x0e\xbd\xb6Q\xb3\x08\xf4\x0c\x1ew\x1d\x07\xa2\x1f\xc4\xccpC\x12U\x0b\x16\xf1\xae^\x949\x1d>{\xe6\xa3\xf4\xed7\n\'tn\xdf'
b'\xba\xde\x9f\n\xdd\x8b/\xb5\xa4$\x98`7\\R\xab)\xbd\x87\xf6\x8d\xbf\x1b\xb0\xe7\x82\xaf\x03ed\x000Pt\xf1\xbfY\xadk_\x05\\u\x13\x08u\xb5*\xa9\xaf@\x06\x88=:\xb0I\xfd#\x81/\xf1&rX?\xd3\xec\xbceR\x9a^5\xb3\xda0%\xc0=\xc7\xca\xcd\xe7\x9a\xa7\x06%}\x0f\xbe@5\'$(Vl\x98Ft\xf6\xa1\xed\xd4\x05\x9a?Q\x84\x8f\xcaI\xf2\xcc\xaa+\x18fx\xbf+\xc0\xf6\x1a\xc2\xa0M\xdf\xb8\xdd\xf4!\xf8\x0fq\xbe\x8fr\xf4=\xf3\x15\xfa\x0b\xc4\xb1ZW!\xf1\xb8\xb6W\x89\xa8T!\xa6\x94Jwi?\x85u]_wH@\x01\xe8\xafC~?&(\x94\x95\xe9\xea?\xcd"\x83.\xb7\x02\xfa\x87\x18\xea\xad\x15\xbc\x8e\\/\xdc\xd4\xbc]\x12\xa8\xc5'
b'\x9f \xf6\xfd\xa9\xeaBwh\xe9:k\xa2\x12o\xb2e\xb3\xc7g\x05\x185\xe6\xef!\xe4tC\x8dR\x0c\x8b\xb1\xe6\xec\x13w{\x0c\xe7\x17\xba\xe9\x9b0Bt\x17\xf8\xbd\xae\x04\xc1\x03]\xb5\xd2T\xdf\xb3\xca }\xca\xd7m\xfe\xfb\xd0\xb0\x04\xdf\xec\xb4\xb2(\xfa\xe1\x80\xf2\x88\x97u;\xa7\xfe\xdf\xa8\xbb\xf8IQ\x12\x1f\xcf\x0b\xcfb\x90\xad\xba\x05\xa7\x17\xc2\x06\xbf\xffdi\xd6v\x8e\xe4c\xb6i\x01\xdb`\xc7\xd3\x1d\xc7O\x9e\xca"\x8a\xbb\xd6\x89\x0f\x12\x8d\xfd2\x92lz\xffv\x82/\x8d\x0f\xba\x9ar&\xf8\xbdH\x0f\xdc\xfa\xf6\n\xc0e\xb5\xe0\x16K\x0cj\xd8\x97\xc4\\\x8c\x11\xfe\xac\xe7\x8d\x9d|y\xd9\xa7\xbaL9\x9b\xd6n\xac\xef\xeb\n\xab\xb1\xe2\x17g|cM\xedQ\xdb\x03}\xa7X'
```

Intenté utilisar .decode("ascii") pero me devuelve:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Security\FCSC\lapin\crack_lapin.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(decrypted.decode("ascii"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x95 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Eso es por gusto, ni con todo el poder de computo q existe se descifra el aes

Comment: Sí, lo sé @Japv -itch, dada una salida que comienza con FCSC estoy tratando de adivinar la entrada.

Comment: AES es un algoritmo [muy diferente de XOR](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/448271/21). Aunque conozcas el texto plano completo y su versión cifrada, no podrás derivar la clave.